# How to compile for all OS X architectures from the command line?

Tags: xcode, gcc

I build my portable C program with `gcc` and `make`.
On OS X I want to include all OS X architectures that the local compiler supports.
If I specify:

```
gcc -arch x86_64 -arch i386 -arch ppc -arch ppc64 ...
```

the build fails on the new Xcode, where `ppc` and `ppc64` are not supported.

How to pick all architectures that the Xcode on the build machine supports?